# WebClient login failure

Tags: c#, wpf, webclient

My Code:

```
 class MyWebClient : WebClient
 {
      private CookieContainer _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

      protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
      {
           WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
           if (request is HttpWebRequest)
           {
               (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
           }
           return request;
      }
 }

 using (var client = new MyWebClient())
 {
      var data = new NameValueCollection
      {
           { "username", "myUser" },
           { "password", "myPw" }
      };
      client.UploadValues("http://www..tv/takelogin.php", data);
 }
```

MNM3.4:
[image: Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4]

Response:
[image]
Building my app i use 3 sites.. with 2 of them everything works fine but with this no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the problem...

```
client.UploadValues("http://www..tv/takelogin.php", data);
```

changed to:

```
client.UploadValues("http://.tv/takelogin.php", data);
```

That means:

```
http://www.MY_SITE.tv
```

dont work, but

```
http://MY_SITE.tv
```

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a `CookieContainer` usually does the trick but you're already sending it. Can you confirm the field names?

Also, for some websites, you'll need to post back the hidden fields. I usually perform a `GET` to the login page and, using an HTML parser (like `HtmlAgilityPack`), I locate the appropriate form and `POST` the login request with all INPUT/SELECT fields I find.

I think the best advice here is to use a debugging proxy like `Fiddler` and try to perform the login from the browser and inspect the generated traffic.